# how to know user is entering wrong password while unlocking device on OS X after loginwindow or sleep?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Suppose user pressed `sleep or login window` on OS X.After that **OS** will promote password to enter in order to resume session.As we know in both cases **sleep/loging window** running application will not terminate.I want to detect if user enters wrong password.

How to detect it?.....Is it possible to detect it?